# Spring Cache refreshing obsolete values

Tags: java, spring, caching

In a Spring-based application I have a service which performs the calculation of some `Index`. `Index` is relatively expensive to calculate (say, 1s) but relatively cheap to check for actuality (say, 20ms). Actual code does not matter, it goes along the following lines:

```
public Index getIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}

public Index calculateIndex() {
    // 1 second or more
}

public boolean isIndexActual(Index index) {
    // 20ms or less
}
```

I'm using Spring Cache to cache the calculated index via `@Cacheable` annotation:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = CacheConfiguration.INDEX_CACHE_NAME)
public Index getIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}
```

We currently configure `GuavaCache` as cache implementation:

```
@Bean
public Cache indexCache() {
    return new GuavaCache(INDEX_CACHE_NAME, CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterWrite(indexCacheExpireAfterWriteSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build());
}

@Bean
public CacheManager indexCacheManager(List<Cache> caches) {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(caches);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

What I also need is to check if cached value is still actual and refresh it (ideally asynchronously) if it is not. So ideally it should go as follows:

- When `getIndex()` is called, Spring checks if there is a value in the cache.

  - If not, new value is loaded via `calculateIndex()` and stored in the cache
  - If yes, the existing value is checked for actuality via `isIndexActual(...)`.

    - If old value is actual, it is returned.
    - If old value is not actual, it is returned, but *removed from the cache and loading of the new value is triggered as well*.

Basically I want to serve the value from the cache very fast (even if it is obsolete) but also trigger refreshing right away.

What I've got working so far is checking for actuality and eviction:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME)
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME, condition = "target.isObsolete(#result)")
public Index getIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}
```

This checks triggers eviction if the result is obsolete and returns the old value immediately even if it is the case. But this does not refresh the value in the cache.

Is there a way to configure Spring Cache to actively refresh obsolete values after eviction?

**Update**

Here's a [MCVE](http://pastebin.com/ibstJe99).

```
public static class Index {

    private final long timestamp;

    public Index(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}

public interface IndexCalculator {
    public Index calculateIndex();

    public long getCurrentTimestamp();
}

@Service
public static class IndexService {
    @Autowired
    private IndexCalculator indexCalculator;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "index")
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "index", condition = "target.isObsolete(#result)")
    public Index getIndex() {
        return indexCalculator.calculateIndex();
    }

    public boolean isObsolete(Index index) {
        long indexTimestamp = index.getTimestamp();
        long currentTimestamp = indexCalculator.getCurrentTimestamp();
        if (index == null || indexTimestamp < currentTimestamp) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final Index index100 = new Index(100);
    final Index index200 = new Index(200);

    when(indexCalculator.calculateIndex()).thenReturn(index100);
    when(indexCalculator.getCurrentTimestamp()).thenReturn(100L);
    assertThat(indexService.getIndex()).isSameAs(index100);
    verify(indexCalculator).calculateIndex();
    verify(indexCalculator).getCurrentTimestamp();

    when(indexCalculator.getCurrentTimestamp()).thenReturn(200L);
    when(indexCalculator.calculateIndex()).thenReturn(index200);
    assertThat(indexService.getIndex()).isSameAs(index100);
    verify(indexCalculator, times(2)).getCurrentTimestamp();
    // I'd like to see indexCalculator.calculateIndex() called after
    // indexService.getIndex() returns the old value but it does not happen
    // verify(indexCalculator, times(2)).calculateIndex();


    assertThat(indexService.getIndex()).isSameAs(index200);
    // Instead, indexCalculator.calculateIndex() os called on
    // the next call to indexService.getIndex()
    // I'd like to have it earlier
    verify(indexCalculator, times(2)).calculateIndex();
    verify(indexCalculator, times(3)).getCurrentTimestamp();
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(indexCalculator);
}
```

I'd like to have the value refreshed shortly after it was evicted from the cache. At the moment it is refreshed on the next call of `getIndex()` first. If the value would have been refreshed right after eviction, this would save me 1s later on.

I've tried `@CachePut`, but it also does not get me the desired effect. The value is refreshed, but the method is always executed, no matter what `condition` or `unless` are.

The only way I see at the moment is to call `getIndex()` twice(second time async/non-blocking). But that's kind of stupid.

Comment: An additional annotation `@CachePut(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME, condition = "target.isObsolete(#result)")`, on `getIndex()`, should do the trick for you.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Just tested it - not quite. `@CachePut` will execute the method in any case, it just won't cache the obsolete result. I want to execute the method if and only if the result was obsolete.

Comment: I donot think this is possible with the @Cacheable annotation, I've been looking for this feature and never found a solution.  What you want is what is referred to as a self populating cache, a cache that will refresh itself but will return obsolete values if the refresh is still running.

Comment: @lexicore Agreed that `@CachePut` will execute the method but if accompanied with `condition = "target.isObsolete(#result)"` it will skip execution when result is *not* obsolete.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond No, this is not what I get in my test. I see the method is always invoked, no matter if the result is obsolete or not. I'll try to prepare a MCVE for this.

Comment: @lexicore After having a closer look at the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html) the behavior encountered is inline as its stated `In contrast to the @Cacheable annotation, this annotation does not cause the advised method to be skipped`. Thus `@CachePut` won't be of use here.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond I've added a MCVE (please see the update). I've tried with `@CachePut` - as you say it does not quite work that way.

Comment: Can someone help me with the resolution of this problem. @lexicore did you get passed this challenge?

Comment: @Einstein_AB Sorry, it was quite a time a go and I don't quite remember the result.

Answer (score 7):

I would say the easiest way of doing what you need is to create a custom Aspect which will do all the magic transparently and which can be reused in more places.

So assuming you have `spring-aop` and `aspectj` dependencies on your class path the following aspect will do the trick.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class IndexEvictorAspect {

    @Autowired
    private Cache cache;

    @Autowired
    private IndexService indexService;

    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @AfterReturning(pointcut="hello.IndexService.getIndex()", returning="index")
    public void afterGetIndex(Object index) {
        if(indexService.isObsolete((Index) index) && lock.tryLock()){
            try {
                Index newIndex = indexService.calculateIndex();
                cache.put(SimpleKey.EMPTY, newIndex);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Several things to note

1. As your `getIndex()` method does not have a parameters it is stored in the cache for key `SimpleKey.EMPTY`
2. The code assumes that IndexService is in the `hello` package.

Comment: and this aspect would behave the same way as the simple CacheEvict annotation, and the call to getIndex will be hanging untill the cache is not calculated once again. - so in best case (single call to cache calculation) will be hold the whole thread, the worst situation you would never get results from cache, because simultaneous calls will force cache to be constantly recalculated.

Comment: @IlyaDyoshin, the case which reflects your needs is the `@AfterReturning` ... So the code will return the result and the cache will be evicted if index is already old. so the code remains the same just you need to change the `@Before` to `@AfterReturning` ... check the updated code above

Comment: but then after the first return and eviction cache is empty, and the system "hangs" or initiates several multiple cache calculations (unless there is a specific blocking)  until the moment the cache is populated again. And the original request is to deliver recent results, even when those are obsolete, until cache is reinitialized with new values.

Comment: Yep, so you can instead of directly evicting the value, just calculate new one  and put it instead of old value. And the code of changing cache values should use some lock so only single calculation takes place. I will try to update my code.

Comment: @Babel and this will be the same code as I had wrote. Look at EDIT1.

Comment: Yep, idea is the same as the requirement is the same :) Just a different approach :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following could refresh the cache in the desired way and keep  the implementation simple and straightforward.

There is nothing *wrong* about writing clear and simple code, provided it satisfies the requirements.

```
@Service
public static class IndexService {
    @Autowired
    private IndexCalculator indexCalculator;

    public Index getIndex() {
        Index cachedIndex = getCachedIndex();

        if (isObsolete(cachedIndex)) {
            evictCache();
            asyncRefreshCache();
        }

        return cachedIndex;
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "index")
    public Index getCachedIndex() {
        return indexCalculator.calculateIndex();
    }

    public void asyncRefreshCache() {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::getCachedIndex);
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "index")
    public void evictCache() { }

    public boolean isObsolete(Index index) {
        long indexTimestamp = index.getTimestamp();
        long currentTimestamp = indexCalculator.getCurrentTimestamp();

        if (index == null || indexTimestamp < currentTimestamp) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that it is going to return lots of null values in multithreaded environment. as you remove the value from key and refresh value in new thread but until the new index is calculated the index in the cache is going to be null. Also you can end up with hundreds of running  async threads which all try to calculate the same index.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT1:

The caching abstraction based on `@Cacheable` and `@CacheEvict` will not work in this case. Those behaviour is following:  during `@Cacheable` call if the value is in cache - return value from the cache, otherwise compute and put into cache and then return; during `@CacheEvict` the value is removed from the cache, so from this moment there is no value in cache, and thus the first incoming call on `@Cacheable` will force the recalculation and putting into cache.  The use `@CacheEvict(condition="")`  will only do the check on condition wether to remove from cache value during this call based on this condition.   So after each invalidation the `@Cacheable` method will run this heavyweight routine to populate cache.

to have the value beign stored in the cache manager, and updated asynchronously, I would propose to reuse following routine:

```
@Inject
@Qualifier("my-configured-caching")
private Cache cache; 
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public Index getIndex() {
    synchronized (this) {
        Index storedCache = cache.get("singleKey_Or_AnythingYouWant", Index.class); 
        if (storedCache == null ) {
             this.lock.lock();
             storedCache = indexCalculator.calculateIndex();
             this.cache.put("singleKey_Or_AnythingYouWant",  storedCache);
             this.lock.unlock();
         }
    }
    if (isObsolete(storedCache)) {
         if (!lock.isLocked()) {
              lock.lock();
              this.asyncUpgrade()
         }
    }
    return storedCache;
}
```

The first construction is sycnhronized, just to block all the upcoming calls to wait until the first call populates cache.

then the system checks wether the cache should be regenerated. if yes, single call for asynchronous update of the value is called, and the current thread is returning the cached value. upcoming call once the cache is in state of recalculation will simply return the most recent value from the cache. and so on.

with solution like this you will be able to reuse huge volumes of memory, of lets say hazelcast cache manager, as well as multiple key-based cache storage  and keep your complex logic of cache actualization and eviction.

OR IF you like the `@Cacheable` annotations, you can do this following way:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "index", sync = true)
public Index getCachedIndex() {
    return new Index();
}

@CachePut(cacheNames = "index")
public Index putIntoCache() {
    return new Index();
}

public Index getIndex() {
    Index latestIndex = getCachedIndex();

    if (isObsolete(latestIndex)) {
        recalculateCache();
    }

    return latestIndex;
}

private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

@Async
public void recalculateCache() {
    if (!lock.isLocked()) {
        lock.lock();
        putIntoCache();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Which is almost the same, as above, but reuses spring's Caching annotation abstraction.

ORIGINAL: 
Why you are trying to resolve this via caching?  If this is simple  value (not key-based, you can organize your code in simpler manner, keeping in mind that spring service is singleton by default)

Something like that:

```
@Service
public static class IndexService {
    @Autowired
    private IndexCalculator indexCalculator;

    private Index storedCache; 
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Index getIndex() {
        if (storedCache == null ) {
             synchronized (this) {
                 this.lock.lock();
                 Index result = indexCalculator.calculateIndex();
                 this.storedCache = result;
                 this.lock.unlock();
             }
        }
        if (isObsolete()) {
             if (!lock.isLocked()) {
                  lock.lock();
                  this.asyncUpgrade()
             }
        }
        return storedCache;
    }

    @Async
    public void asyncUpgrade() {
        Index result = indexCalculator.calculateIndex();
        synchronized (this) {
             this.storedCache = result;
        }
        this.lock.unlock();
    }

    public boolean isObsolete() {
        long currentTimestamp = indexCalculator.getCurrentTimestamp();
        if (storedCache == null || storedCache.getTimestamp() < currentTimestamp) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

i.e.  first call is synchronized and you have to wait until the results are populated.    Then if stored value is obsolete the system will perform asynchronous update of the value, but the current thread will receive the stored "cached" value.

I had also introduced the reentrant lock to restrict single upgrade of stored index at time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'd say the code you posted is a "simpler manner". At least not compared to two annotations and a cache config.  
And I'm really interested in a cache-base solution for cache. I have no keys in this case/example but in others. I'm interested in a general solution.

Comment: Well yes, it looks not simpler, but it does, what you have requested: to return latest cache value, regardless of its obsoletenes, and in case its value is obsolete trigger upgrade of the cache.   The annotations, are simple abstraction to support memoize-like calls: in the call to `@Cacheable` return cached value, if there is no, then compute, put in cache and return. in case `CacheEvict`-annotated is called remove from the cache stored value. this caching operations should not work on the entity based on the value in the cache.

Comment: If the caches are evicted based on the time, than I would suggest for you to have scheduling based routine which will be putting the results of its computations via `@CachePut`  methods.   If you want to store the cache in some caching solution, than you can inject the preconfigured `Cache` (have a look at edit)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Guava LoadingCache in your index service, like shown in the code sample below:

```html
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
 .maximumSize(1000)
 .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
 .build(
     new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
       public Graph load(Key key) { // no checked exception
         return getGraphFromDatabase(key);
       }
       public ListenableFuture<Graph> reload(final Key key, Graph prevGraph) {
         if (neverNeedsRefresh(key)) {
           return Futures.immediateFuture(prevGraph);
         } else {
           // asynchronous!
           ListenableFutureTask<Graph> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(new Callable<Graph>() {
             public Graph call() {
               return getGraphFromDatabase(key);
             }
           });
           executor.execute(task);
           return task;
         }
       }
     });
```

You can create an async reloading cache loader by calling Guava's method:

```html
public abstract class CacheLoader<K, V> {
...

  public static <K, V> CacheLoader<K, V> asyncReloading(
      final CacheLoader<K, V> loader, final Executor executor) {
      ...
      
  }
}
```

The trick is to run the reload operation in a separate thread, using a ThreadPoolExecutor for example:

- On first call, the cache is populated by the load() method, thus it may take some time to answer,
- On subsequent calls, when the value needs to be refreshed, it's being computed asynchronously while still serving the stale value. It will serve the updated value once the refresh has completed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be something like

```
@Autowired
IndexService indexService; // self injection

@Cacheable(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME)
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME, condition = "target.isObsolete(#result) && @indexService.calculateIndexAsync()")
public Index getIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}

public boolean calculateIndexAsync() {
    someAsyncService.run(new Runable() {
        public void run() {
            indexService.updateIndex(); // require self reference to use Spring caching proxy
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@CachePut(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME)
public Index updateIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}
```

Above code has a problem, if you call to `getIndex()` again while it is being updated, it will be calculated again. To prevent this, it better to don't use `@CacheEvict` and let the `@Cacheable` return the obsolete value until the index has done calculated.

```
@Autowired
IndexService indexService; // self injection

@Cacheable(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME, condition = "!(target.isObsolete(#result) && @indexService.calculateIndexAsync())")
public Index getIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}

public boolean calculateIndexAsync() {
    if (!someThreadSafeService.isIndexBeingUpdated()) {
        someAsyncService.run(new Runable() {
            public void run() {
                indexService.updateIndex(); // require self reference to use Spring caching proxy
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}

@CachePut(cacheNames = INDEX_CACHE_NAME)
public Index updateIndex() {
    return calculateIndex();
}
```